# UITableViewCell Swipe right to trigger action or perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) for it's swipe left and swipe right menu buttons. It's working pretty well, I just need to customize the swipe right to trigger an action or perform a segue when the user finished dragging the cell to the right.

I have one button on the left side and want the action triggered when the user finishes dragging, as illustrated in the attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to look into the cell's `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and define the actions you need. You'd also need to look at the direction of the swipe and the state it finished in. Here's an example from my custom UITableViewCell subclass:

```
- (void)_pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellDidBeginPan:)])
            [self.delegate cellDidBeginPan:self];

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cellDidEndPan:)])
            [self.delegate cellDidEndPan];
   }
}
```